# JS create a graph type json from plain json

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following object:

```js
let response = [
{ from: A, to: B, cost: 1 },
{ from: B, to: C, cost: 2 },
{ from: B, to: D, cost: 3 },
{ from: C, to: D, cost: 2 }]
```

I would like to get the following object

```
{
  A: {B: 1},
  B: {A: 1, C: 2, D: 3},
  C: {B: 2, D: 2},
  D: {B: 3, C: 2}
}
```

I was trying to use reduce to improve the performance. But I'm not sure.

Comment: What are `A` and `B`?

Comment: `reduce` does not improve performance over a normal loop, write it with simple syntax first. Can you please show us your solution/approach? What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, something a little screwy, because you've got only 4 input items, but in your output you're representing 8 states.  There's an implicit assumption, I guess, that 'cost' from A to B is same as cost from B to A (?)

Assuming that's true, and also assuming A, B, C, D are actually 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D', this code [ES6] will output what you have asked for:

```
function foo() {
    var response = [
        { from: 'A', to: 'B', cost: 1 },
        { from: 'B', to: 'C', cost: 2 },
        { from: 'B', to: 'D', cost: 3 },
        { from: 'C', to: 'D', cost: 2 }
    ];
    self = this;
    self.result = {};
    response.forEach(function(item) {
        if (!result[item.from]) {
            self.result[item.from]={};
        }
        if (!result[item.to]) {
            self.result[item.to]={};
        }
        self.result[item.from][item.to]= item.cost; 
        self.result[item.to][item.from]=item.cost;
    });
    return this.result;
 }
```